# Apple Push Notification Service, Group notifications together

Tags: ios, ios5, notifications, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have searched through all of apples docs for their push service.  The app I am designing sometimes pushes many notifications.  These notifications are very useful if you are *inside* the app, because they serve to update the UI.  However, if you are *not inside* the app, you will collect many notifications on the home screen, which is just a bad user experience.

I would only like to tell the user about a type of notification once if the app is not open.

Google has a very similar concept, called a Collapsible Key, as seen here:
[GCM Messages](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/gcm.html#collapse)

Basically, notifications can be grouped, and collapsed so only one of each type is displayed.  I am trying to find a way to do this, or emulate the behavior someone either client or server side.  Thanks for the help!